# =?UTF?Q? Newsgroup string from ASCII to Unicode

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, kotlin

I am now facing a problem with the character encoding of server responses.

What I get are multiple strings all encoded the following way:

```
=?UTF?Q?Gr=c3=bcnes?=
```

I tried to simple extract the text part and decode it someway but without success. Is there any common way to do this?

Comment: can you share code snippet of how you are doing this?

Comment: Well that's the point. I tried simple string operation and afterwards something like `StandartCharSets.utf8.encode(txt.toByteArray())`.. But that lead to the same string as before.

Comment: Are you sure that server response is encoded in utf8?

Comment: It should be ASCII encoded but with this weird "=c3=bc" instead of a german 'ü' character

Comment: Are you running on the JVM? There is no way to get a UTF-8 encoded `String`, as all strings are in UTF-16. If the response is ASCII encoded, you should read it into a `String` through an ASCII decoder. But the 'ü' will be lost one way or another, since ASCII doesn't support that character.

Comment: But how is this case usually handled. I am running on android and I know that they are encoded by default.. What i am looking for is some kind of algorithm to convert this string to its "UTF" equivalent

Comment: = might be from [QP encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). If not that, something similar.

Comment: Okay so I found this site http://www.webatic.com/run/convert/qp.php which basically does exactly what I am looking for. I need this kind of translation in java :/

Comment: Assuming you are using HTTP, you should be looking in the [headers](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html). That's what a library would do. Perhaps there is one that deals with QUOTED-PRINTABLE.

Comment: Yeah i know thats how i can determine if i need to change the string or not .. what i want to know is how exactly i can change it to archive my desired representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i finally found the proper way of doing this.
`QuotedPrintableCodec().decode(inputString)` part of the [the Apache Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html) was exactly what i was looking for.